# Control device functions in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, operating-system, wifi

I'm thinking about starting developing an app to Windows Phone 8 where user can manage the status of device's basic functions, e.g. toggle on/off Wifi/Bluetooth/Network data, alter Brightness, etc. Something like the [Insider App](http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/insider-pro/4cd69917-a022-40ce-8272-d258998746aa) does (although it seems to only create  shortcuts to these functions).

It's something supposed to be possible in an app, but I just couldn't find anything about this, and I'm almost sure it's not possible. It doesn't seem to have such function under WP8 Dev Reference.

The only reference to something like this is [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1395/is-there-any-app-that-can-switch-profiles-based-on-location/1398#1398), but I really would appreciate if someone could confirm that's not possible (maybe something could have been changed along this year), and if it's really not possible, I'd appreciate if someone could point out where in reference Microsoft affirms it (or it just doesn't?).

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know - for now you cannot do that. One thing you can - is to create a shortcut to settings page, where you can turn on/off connections.

Here are some links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/0c1a2224-1aeb-49ed-84a3-f40ea899cef3/turning-off-and-on-3gwifibluetooth-etc-cvb?forum=wpdevelop

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/5d5da1a8-cc84-4736-8ee5-7e4cacb7f5c5/how-to-enabledisable-wifi-programmatically?forum=wpdevelop

There are also some user voices regarding this problem (to turn on/off omitting settings page):
http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2284156-one-tap-tile-to-toggle-on-off-wifi-bluetooth-d

http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2408839-quick-switch-wifi-and-bluetooth-on-off

Comment: Thanks Romasz. As I suspected, unfortunately Microsoft seem to be still developing some kind of UAC for Windows Phone 8, what would allow this kind of flexibility to us, programmers. Let's wait 'til WP 8.1, maybe this could be improved, as I'm sure that this kind of control would allow better apps to be developed (and I'm sure that Microsoft is interested in more apps, btw).